# StructureMap Convention - Differences between Registy.AddType and Registry.For().Use()

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

Short question. Exists some diference between `registry.AddType(pluginType, type);` and `registry.For(pluginType).Use(type);` ?

Code:

```
public class BasicConvention : ConfigurableRegistrationConvention
{
    public override void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
            if (something)
                registry.For(pluginType).Use(type).Singleton();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class BasicConvention : ConfigurableRegistrationConvention
{
    public override void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
            if (something)
                registry.AddType(pluginType, type);
        }
    }
}
```

Using WhatDoIHave() I can see the same:

Using AddType:

```
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
PluginType                  Namespace                          Lifecycle     Description                                                                                                                                               Name                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISession                    Paf.Application.Session            Transient     Paf.Application.Session ('Paf.Application.Session, Paf.Modules.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')                              Paf.Application.Session,... (Default)
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

Using For().Use():

```
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
PluginType                  Namespace                          Lifecycle     Description                                                                                                                                               Name                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISession                    Paf.Application.Session            Singleton     Paf.Application.Session                                                                                                                                (Default)                               
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

The only difference is in the description ...

Somebody?

Comment: In your example, you are specifying `Singleton()` in the first version of `BasicConvention.Process`, but not in the second version. This doesn't affect the question overall, but it does make for different Lifecycle values (Transient vs. Singleton) in the `WhatDoIHave()` results.

Comment: Yes, doesn't affect the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `registry.AddType(pluginType, type)` is basically shorthand for chaining together `For` and `Use` as in `registry.For(pluginType).Use(type)`.

Calling `registry.AddType(pluginType, type)` causes a direct call to `Registry.alter.set` with the plugin type and the concrete type specified together.

Calling `registry.For(pluginType).Use(type)` chains together `For` and `Use`. The call to `For` returns a new `GenericFamilyExpression` (the constructor calls `Registry.alter.set` for the interface type), and the call to `Use` ends up calling `Registry.alter.set` to make the concrete type the default for the plugin family.

See the source code for [Registry.cs](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap/Configuration/DSL/Registry.cs) and [GenericFamilyExpression.cs](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap/Configuration/DSL/Expressions/GenericFamilyExpression.cs), and other classes in the [StructureMap source](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/tree/master/src).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not entirely correct. They are not the same. Which is surprisingly is indicated at the end of an answer. `Use` will set default instance for plugin (type) and `AddType` will not. So you will not be able to use Structure map as service locator with AddType. You can have this error `No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type <type>`